# how to change fancybox scrolling to left to right?

Tags: jquery, scroll, fancybox

Fancybox looks great, but when I click on the right or next arrow, the the image drops in from the top. I find that strange. When I see arrow like that, I picture the upcoming image as being off the screen in that direction. When it drops in from the top, it's jarring to me.

So how do you make fancybox scroll horizontally? There seem to be parameters for just about everything but not for scroll direction. (My javascript skills are limited to minor tweaks in other people's work.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, half answer is coming, it's friday night and I'm leaving work soon, but change the plugin:

```
    changeOut: function () {

        var wrap = F.wrap,
            current = F.current,
            cleanUp = function () {
                $(this).trigger('onReset').remove();
            };

        wrap.removeClass('fancybox-opened');

        if (current.prevEffect === 'elastic') {
            if( F.coming.index < F.current.index) {
            wrap.animate({
                'opacity': 0,
                right :'+=200px'
            }, {
                duration: current.prevSpeed,
                easing: current.prevEasing,
                complete: cleanUp
            });
            }
            else {
                wrap.animate({
                'opacity': 0,
                left :'+=200px'
            }, {
                duration: current.prevSpeed,
                easing: current.prevEasing,
                complete: cleanUp
            });
            }

        } else {
            wrap.fadeOut(current.prevEffect === 'fade' ? current.prevSpeed : 0, cleanUp);
        }
    }
```

this is only half of it, `changeIn: function()` doesn't seem to have `F.coming.index`, which i used to find out which direction it was going.

Comment: I liked the transition, just not from the top. I found that changing startPos from top to left allows the slide to continue, but it's the same both prev and next.     `if (current.nextEffect === 'elastic') {
    startPos = F._getPosition(true);
    startPos.opacity = 0;
    startPos.left = (parseInt(startPos.left, 10) - 200) + 'px';

    wrap.css(startPos).show().animate({
     opacity: 1,
     left: '+=200px'
    }, {
     duration: current.nextSpeed,
     easing: current.nextEasing,
     complete: F._afterZoomIn
    });`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @little-big-bot. Stackflow cut me off before I could say that before. ;-) Is there a (relatively simple) way to make the next/prev buttons work like next/prev. With my fix all I get is the next effect, whether next or previous.

Comment: Ah, no prob. I'll see what I can find. If I can't figure it out, `prevEffect: fade` is another option.